# How to sort data using Cursor with Content Provider and Cursor Adapter?

Tags: cursor, android-contentprovider, android-cursoradapter

I have a `Content Provider` and a `Cursor Adapter`. One of the columns in my table is an `int`. I want to order my table by this column, so the `Adapter` will show the data accordingly. I tried to do this:
In the `Activity`:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
                PetContract.Dogs.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null,
                PetContract.Dogs.DATE + " ASC");

        testAdapter = new TestAdapter(this, c);
        c.close();
        list.setAdapter(testAdapter);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
        registerForContextMenu(list);
```

In the `Adapter` constructor:

```
public TestAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
    }
```

But it didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. In my `Activity`:

```
 @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(this,
                PetContract.Dogs.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                PetContract.Dogs.DATE + " collate localized asc"
        );
    }
```